# Java equivalent for Python app-engine model/entity representation and operation

Tags: java, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

Consider the following app-engine models in python.

```
class Account(ndb.Model):
  email = ndb.StringProperty()
  nickname = ndb.StringProperty()
  phone = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Invitation(ndb.Model):
  sender = ndb.StructuredProperty(Account, required=True)
  recipient = ndb.StructuredProperty(Account, required=True)
  message = ndb.StringProperty()
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

  @classmethod
  def get_recipient(cls, sender, date):
    qry = Invitation.query(ndb.AND(Invitation.sender == sender, Invitation.date == date)).fetch(projection=['recipient']))
    return qry
```

How would I rewrite the code above in Java? Notice that Account is a proper entity/model -- not subject to the restrictions imposed by java's `EmbeddedEntity`. Also, if the reply is JDO (please provide code), [the google site has a warning saying](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2#Unsupported_Features_of_JDO_3_0) (which I don't understand):

> Polymorphic queries. You cannot perform a query of a class to get
>   instances of a subclass. Each class is represented by a separate
>   entity kind in the datastore.

Does this warning mean there are things we can do with python that we cannot do with java on app-engine?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the reason you want to convert your app-engine backend to java is because of the Google Eclipse Plugin (GEP) to create app-engine connected devices. If that's the case, the savings you make by developping in python outweighs the benefits of using GEP.

The warning you quote is not about compound objects, which is what your Account class is to your Invitation class.

Again, unless you have a definite reason for going to java (other than GEP), you should stick with Python. There is so much less extraneous mess to deal with.

Comment: You could not have put it better. I can't believe there are no upvotes. I am at a company with a large java appengine server. Coming from years of python on app engine it is really a huge mess. Why is that do you think? Just the datastore.Entity alone is so much more of an ordeal then the simple ndb.Model or even db.Model